# python: jsonify show only one output

Tags: python, json, flask

There are 10 outputs in json but it is only the first output is shown. How to show all 10 outputs?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import requests
from lxml import html


@app.route('/saptop', methods=['GET'])
def saptop():

    page_indo = requests.get('http://www.waterfrontsekuritas.com/marketview')
    indo = html.fromstring(page_indo.content)
    indo = indo.xpath('//table[@id="top-gainer"]//td/text()')

    col = ['Stockcode','Lastprice','Prevprice','pc','Change','Tfreq','Vol','Value']

    c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,indo))]    
    return jsonify({'Stock': c1})
```

The current output only shown the first one

```
{
  "Stock": [
    {
      "Stockcode": "BOSS",
      "Lastprice": "1,400",
      "Prevprice": "1,120",
      "pc": "25.00",
      "Change": "280",
      "Tfreq": "3,640",
      "Vol": "23,087,100",
      "Value": "29,132,765,000"
    }
  ]
}
```

when `change to c1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in indo]` , the output as below which is wrong also, all the string is seperated by letter and number:

```
{
  "Stock": [
    {
      "Stockcode": "B",
      "Lastprice": "O",
      "Prevprice": "S",
      "pc": "S"
    },
    {
      "Stockcode": "1",
      "Lastprice": ",",
      "Prevprice": "4",
      "pc": "0",
      "Change": "0"
    },
    {
      "Stockcode": "1",
      "Lastprice": ",",
      "Prevprice": "1",
      "pc": "2",
      "Change": "0"
    },
    {
      "Stockcode": "2",
      "Lastprice": "5",
      "Prevprice": ".",
      "pc": "0",
      "Change": "0"
    },
```

how to shown all 10 results correctly in Flask? It is json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the list format from

`indo = ['abc','123','cde','efg','112','123']` to `[['abc','123'],['cde','efg'],['112','123']]`

for your example, change just add

```
indo = indo.xpath('//table[@id="top-gainer"]//td/text()')
indo = [indo[n:n+8] for n in range(0, len(indo), 8)]
```